# react-dropzone onDrop firing twice

Tags: reactjs, proxy, react-dropzone

So I'm trying to add a pretty simple file upload to my React + Redux App and I found that Dropzone to be the most convinient way to do it. Here's my setup.

I have a `FileInput` component

```
import React from 'react'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

class FileInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(files) {
        // For Redux form
        if (this.props.input) {
            const {input: {onChange}} = this.props;
            onChange(files[0])
        }
        else if(this.props.onChange){
            this.props.onChange(files[0])
        }
        else{
            console.warn('redux-form-dropzone => Forgot to pass onChange props ?');
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Dropzone onDrop={ this.onChange } {...this.props} >
                Drag&Drop the image <br/> or click to select one
            </Dropzone>
        )
    }
}
export default FileInput
```

And I use it on tha page like this:

```
<FileInput
    onChange={(file) => console.log('dropped', file)}
    className='add-avatar-dropzone'
    activeClassName='dropzone-active'
/>
```

(console.log used for debugging purposes ofcource)

But when I try to drop a file, I get 2 log outputs. The first being the file I dropped, the second - some kind of a Proxy, probably provided by react itself...

[image: console output example]

I wonder how to get rid of that proxy and why is it doing that in the first place?

**Thing I tried**

Couple obvious problem-points I tried to eliminate, but did not seem to make any change.

1. Renaming the `onChange` function to something else like `handleDrop` and rewriting it as `handleDrop = (files) => {`
2. Removing the constructor (seems weird to assign something to itself)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a simple matter and it's really silly for me not to think of it.

The `onChange` prop in the code above got passed on to `Dropzone` and then to the input field, wich was the source of the confusion.

I modified the code to work like this:

```
render() {

    const { onChange, ...rest } = this.props

    return (
        <Dropzone onDrop={ this.onChange } {...rest} >
            Drag&Drop the image <br/> or click to select one
        </Dropzone>
    )
}
```

That works just fine